# Process can not get more than 30% CPU

Tags: cpu, process

I'm running a program that is known to be CPU time consuming, but it cannot get more than 30% for me which causes issues and crashes.

Are there any parameters limiting the process to 30% that I can change?

Comment: Is your program wait or otherwise limited? Use `top` to observe what is going on, and perhaps edit a screen shot (well, a cut and paste will do) from `top` into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your program is controlled by cpulimit application

```
# cpulimit -l 30 /bin/yourprogram &
```

The above command will start application but will not allow application to use more than 30% of cpu

[cpulimit.1.html](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/cpulimit.1.html)

[cpulimit examples](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-limit-cpu-usage-on-ubuntu-12-10)

Comment: Thank you PKumar. Actually cpulimit is not even installed. Maybe there is some other tools that limit CPU usage ?

Comment: @Spider `sudo apt-get install cpulimit`

Comment: @Spider check this page if it can help you  http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2014/11/04/restricting-process-cpu-usage-using-nice-cpulimit-and-cgroups

Comment: Actually, I just want to know if something else can limit CPU. My process is not able to get more than 30% which causes a crashe.